# Burlap java server to work with python client

Tags: java, python, server, client, hessian

I'm trying to connect a burlap java server with a python client but I can't find any detail whatsoever regarding how to use burlap with python or if it even is implemented for python. Any ideas? Can I build burlap python clients? Any resources? Would using a hessian python client work with a java burlap server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Burlap and Hessian are 2 different (but related) RPC protocols, with Burlap being XML based and Hessian being binary.

They're both also pretty ancient, so if you have an opportunity to use something else, I'd highly recommend it. If not, then you're going to have to find a Burlap lib for Python.

Since it seems that a Burlap lib for Python simply doesn't exist (at least anymore), your best choice is probably to make a small Java proxy that communicates with a more recent protocol with the Python side and in Burlap with the Java server.

Comment: I know I have to find a burlap lib for Python. The problem is, I can't find any. That was also between my questions. Is there any? I can't change anything for now, worst case scenario I move to hessian but that's worst case

Comment: Take each sentence in your posting that's terminated with a question mark and put them into Google instead of here. Well, except for the last one.

Comment: Funny but I've already done that and this is my last resort

Comment: Well, it looks like you're out of luck. 10 years is a long time for a protocol, especially one that was never really that widely used to start with. Seems like they've even dumped it at Caucho, even though there's still documentation for Hessian.

Comment: See my edit, that's what I would do if I had to support a legacy system like that.

Comment: Thank you. I will see if I do the proxy thing or just try it with hessian